# Unix command line arguments to kill process after a single print

Tags: c, unix

I need to pass unix arguments to run C file so that it prints a certain line "Hello World" a single time only. The file uses fork to print the sentence multiple times but I need to send a kill signal to kill the processes after the sentence "Hello World" is printed once only.

I tried

```
./"file name" sleep 4 KILL -9
```

I do not think I am using the right syntax here.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
   int m, i, c = 0;
   pid_t pgid;

   m = atoi(argv[1]);

   for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
   if(fork() > 0)
   {
       c = 1;
   }
}

if(!c)
{
    pgid = getpgid(getpid());
    setpgid(getpid(), getpid());
    kill(m * pgid, SIGINT);
}

sleep(3);

if(fork() > 0)
{
    puts("Hello World");
}

return 0;
}
```

It is printing few times and then it hangs.

Comment: You want to kill that program when it is executing a certain iteration of your loop?

Comment: try `./"file_name" &; pid=$! ; sleep 4 ; kill -9 $pid` . You probably will want to adjust the `sleep` value. Modern `sleep`s honor sub-seconds, like `.5`. . Normally `kill -9 $pid` is consider bad form in shell programming, but given you want it to die as fast as possible (basically!), so don't get in the habit of using `-9` except when you know for sure you need to. I don't think it will be possible to manage signaling to a process with the precision required to allow only one "Hello World" emitted. Assuming this is for a class, re-read your material closely for a hint. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Shellter.. I tried what you have suggested but ended up with the line being rinted multiple times as well. My understanding is that variable "m" contains the int result of argv[1] which is later multiplied by the GPID and sent to KILL(). The number that is being passed by "m" should result with successfully killing all the processes at once maybe without even passing the kill command from the command line because it exists within the code, but I am unable to determine what should be that int "m"